# GXT TreeGrid row numbering in a heirarchical manner

Tags: gwt, gxt, treegrid

I am writing a tree grid widget where I want to number the rows so that every root node is numbered in sequence and children nodes are numbered independently beginning from 1 within each parent and preferably having the parent's number prefixed; a multi-level row numbering, if one may call it so. The built-in row numberer does not seem to do so. Any ideas on how I schould proceed?
I could write my own column and manage its contents but I find it odd that there isn't some standard way of doing this already since it is a fiarly common manner of indexing hierarchical data.

Comment: GXT 2 or 3? They have very different models of how to render in a tree/grid/treegrid, so that detail will be important to give a precise answer.

Comment: Well, I am using version 3 but if the solution is going to be so tightly coupled to the version, that means I would not be able to upgrade my library at a later point of time.

Comment: Nope, just needed to make sure before I started writing, since the API is a bit different. I'll have it up soonish...